# Does Curator remove indices from entire elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-curator

I have a cluster of 4 elasticsearch servers and was wondering if curator will remove indices from the entire cluster when ran from one server or if I need to run it on all servers?

Answer (score 0):

It deletes from the whole cluster. It uses the Elasticsearch API, rather than any file system logic.